# Post increment operator for user defined types's behavior

Tags: c++, g++

I was going through some book and I decided to write my own implementation of post-increment operator for user defined type. Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class X
{
    int a;

    public:
    X(int x=1):a(x){}

    X operator++(int)
    {
        X oldobj = *this;
        (*this).a++;
        return oldobj;
    }

int get(){return a;}

};

int main()
{
    X obj,obj2;
    obj++ = obj2;
    cout<< obj.get() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect the output to be `1` since obj2's value will be copied after the increment is done. But the output was `2`.

Thoughts?

P.S.  I know this code will not win any medals and its fallacies. It is just for my understanding. Incidentally, `++obj = obj2` returns `1`;

Is the behavior undefined?

Comment: `(*this).a++` is more usually written as `this->a++` (or just `a++`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your syntax tells you, the postfix operator returns a copy of the old value, so that's what gets incremented, not your object.

Basically,

```
obj++ = obj2;
```

Will do this:

```
X tempObj = obj;
obj ++;
tempObj = obj2;
```

You're assigning `obj2` to a temporary variable.

Answer (score 2):

`obj++` returns a temporary object holding the old value.

So, although "`obj2`'s value will be copied after the increment is done" is true, it's not copied into the original `obj` at all :)

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour is actually well-defined.

You are assigning to the result of `obj++`, which is a temporary - a copy of `obj` from before the post-increment. This assignment does not affect `obj`, which retains its value of `2` from the increment.

The code is roughly equivalent to:

```
X temp = obj;
obj++;
temp = obj2;
```